# Free scrolling vertical and snap scroll horizontal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, unity-game-engine, scroll

I want to scroll up and down freely but when I scroll horizontal to snap on the next panel. I found a few methods but there are problems with the panels containg multiple elements with a grid layout, they all get placed in the centre.

I made a mockup of the menu. Mabye it will make you understand what I need.
[image]

Comment: You will likely need two different scrollviews.

Comment: Please add some screenshots and code snippets of what you have done so far, it will be easier for people to give advice :)

Comment: @CaTs the problem is that I guess this is setup all in the inspector using Unity.UI so there might be no code actually

Comment: @derHugo then the question can describe a hierarchy of UI elements or include some screenshots of the inspector.

Comment: @CaTs you don't have to tell **me** but yeah sure the more information the better

Comment: I think Draco18s already made a point: I also would make an only vertical free scroll for each column and than wrap those all into one only horizontal snapped scroll

Comment: @derHugo but how will I make all those columns move at the same time if they are in 3 different scroll views?

Comment: you could synchronize (in a script linked to the [onValueChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-onValueChanged.html) event) their [ScrollRect.NormalizedVerticalPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-verticalNormalizedPosition.html) .. assuming they all have the same height offcourse